# how can i save more than one image in the database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, httppostedfilebase

I just want to save the route of the images in the database.
So i try this.

And i get this error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is my Controller

```
public ActionResult SaveImages(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> img, Imagenes images)
    {
        foreach (var n in img)
        {
            var PhotoUrl = Server.MapPath("/images" + n.FileName);
            if (n != null && n.ContentLength > 0)
                n.SaveAs(PhotoUrl);
            images.imgUrl = "/images" + n.FileName;

            db.Imagenes.Add(images);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View("Index");

    }
```

This is my model class

```
    public partial class Imagenes
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string imgUrl { get; set; }
}
```

my View

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveImages", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div>
    <input type="file" name="img" id="img" multiple />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
</div>}
```

Comment: What is not working ? You do not really need the second parameter in your method ? How does your razor view looks like ?

Comment: yes I need it because THROUGH the second parameter is that I save the image in the database

Comment: Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: just right here: var PhotoUrl = Server.MapPath("/images" + n.FileName);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is nothing about the image saving part, but I'm assuming it's the use of your `images` property...

As you didn't specify where that property comes from, MVC automatically assumes that's a POST Variable, and in your HTML, you have nothing of sorts...

change your action code to:

```
public ActionResult SaveImages(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> img)
{
    const string folderToUpload = "/images";

    foreach (var n in img)
    {
        var imageToUpload = folderToUpload + n.FileName;
        var photoUrl = Server.MapPath(imageToUpload);

        if (n != null && n.ContentLength > 0) {

            n.SaveAs(photoUrl);      // save to folder

            var images = new Imagenes {
               imgUrl = imageToUpload
            };

            db.Imagenes.Add(images); // add to repository
            db.SaveChanges();        // save repositorychanges
        }
    }

    return redirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I'm also assuming that `db` was already injected in your constructor, and it's not `NULL`

Code edited:

- create a constant variable to have the folder to upload, so you don't repeat that code over and over
- create a variable to hold the full path of the image, so you don't repeat that code over and over (remember: DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself)
- save to database only if the file was saved
- create a new variable to hold your object to be saved
- redirect to the action using `redirectToAction` as you might have some calls in your `Index` and only redirecting to the View would give you an error
- to be persistence, change the `PhotoUrl` to `photoUrl` (local variables = start with lowercase)